# How to send Whatsapp invitation link to join a group using php

Tags: php

Actually, i am working on a application which sends a whatsapp invitation link to user to join a group when we submit a from using php so can someone please suggest me something..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you want to send ? By Mail

Comment: Not on mail... i want to send on mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a SMS API to send message to phone number submitted by user. Use the whatsapp group chat link in the SMS messsage body. There are several SMS API's available.